# Selecting polygons based on area of overlap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, select-by-attribute, overlapping-features

I am working with point data in QGIS, where the points represent electricity pylons on a transmission grid.

I have created buffers with a 1 km radius around each of the points, and I would like to know if there is any way that I can extract buffers from this layer based on the area of overlap with other 1km buffers.

I only want the buffers which share less than 10% of their interior space with another 1 km buffer in the same layer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a SpatiaLite database, import your point buffer dataset into it, rename it to `pbuffer`, start DB Manager, open the SpatiaLite DB, and run the following two queries (one at a time):

1. Query #1 creates a table with the overlapping areas of the point buffers.

```sql
   CREATE TABLE pbi AS SELECT pb1.id AS id1, pb2.id AS id2,
                              st_intersection(pb1.geom, pb2.geom)
   AS geom
   FROM pbuffer AS pb1, pbuffer AS pb2
   WHERE pb1.id <> pb2.id AND st_overlaps(pb1.geom, pb2.geom);
```

2. Query #2 will, for each point buffer, give you the area of overlap with other point buffers (`area`), and it also produces a "flag" (`ok`) that is True (1) if the area of overlap is less than 10% of their interior space (for point buffers with 1 km radius).

```sql
   SELECT pbi.id1, st_union(geom) AS geom,
          st_area(st_union(geom)) AS area,
          st_area(st_union(geom))/(pi()*1000000) < 0.1 as ok
   FROM pbi
   GROUP BY pbi.id1;
```

[image]

Comment: Why create spatialite when you can run the sql as virtual layers

Comment: This is a matter of taste. Virtual layers will work, but I guess you will have to go via a layer (*Load as new layer*) between step 1 and 2. Combining the steps into one query and using Virtual layers would be elegant, but I think it would hide what is going on.